# Why does ImageView.setAlpha() set alpha to multiple ImageViews in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, listadapter

I'm implementing a custom gallery that allows multiple photo selection.

I'm using a `GridView` with a simple `ImageAdapter` class extended from `BaseAdapter`.

Here is my `ImageAdapter` class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setLongClickable(true);
        holder.imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                int id = arg0.getId();
                ImageView img = (ImageView) arg0;
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    Log.d("PRTAG", "deselecting img with id: " + img.getId());
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgview_noborder);
                    img.setAlpha(255);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    Log.d("PRTAG", "selecting img with id: " + img.getId());
                    img.setAlpha(128);
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgview_border);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
                        "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.id = position;

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

All images are added correctly, the `onClick()` method works fine (it opens up the correct image).

The problem is with `onLongClick()`. I'm adding a custom background and setting the alpha (`128` - image selected, `255` - image not selected) on the image that is long clicked on. The actual selection works fine, it selects the right images.

The actual problem is that the background and alpha are set to multiple (random) images when scrolling the grid view.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get familiar with `ListView` views reusage concept. Basically `GridView` reuses views while scrolling. So if You change some view, then it obviously will be changed then reused (until You're not changing the property of it in `getView()`). Checkout [Google I/O video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) with more explanation about `ListView`, because most of it applies to `GridView` also.

So, if You need to have some views with different properties, then You have 2 options:

- Make views of another type (in other words use [getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and [getItemViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and change types dynamically with calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`);
- Store specific items positions (or some kind of flags in `ViewHolder`, in Your case it might be `thumbnailsselection` array information) and setup view property every `getView()` call using stored before information;

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and the Google I/O video is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your views are reusable, it means that you need to update alpha every time `getView` is invoked. Not only on LongPress

Create `ArrayList selectedImages` ivar for all selected images.
 - onLongPress add/remove image to `selectedImages`
 - In your `getView` method check if image is stored in a list and set according `alpha` value

Comment: it's better to store item positions or tags in `selectedImages` array of course. Hope you got an idea

Comment: Thanks for mentioning getView, I've been struggling with an issue for some time :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use `ImageView`'s click and long click listeners in `getView()` method, but to use `ListView`'s or `GridView`'s `setOnItemLongClickListener` and `setOnItemClickListener`.

In these listeners you should just save the state of an item, selected or not, and in `getView()` method you should look-up the item's state and do the following:

```
            if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                Log.d("PRTAG", "deselecting img with id: " + img.getId());
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgview_noborder);
                img.setAlpha(255);
            } else {
                Log.d("PRTAG", "selecting img with id: " + img.getId());
                img.setAlpha(128);
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgview_border);
            }
```

Basically, in every `getView()` call you should verify your data object state and **always** adjust the view's state before returning it.

Comment: I ended up using `ImageView`'s click and long click listeners in `getView()` method, but as you said, in the listeners I just save the view's state and in `getView()` I apply the correct properties.

Comment: You may end up with a sluggish scroll if getView() is not kept as simple and as fastest as possible. That's why you use a holder object there, also mentioned in World of listview Google I/O video. Think about it, every time getView() is called, new objects are created for listeners, instead of adding once in ListView.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I'll use `setOnItemLongListener` and `setOnItemClickListener`. Thank you for the tip.